# Disable resharper autosave on new line

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

I have a bit of a weird problem here. I am running visual stduio 2017 with resharper and any time I press enter in a .ts file, the file is automatically saved. The weird thing is, this only happens for .ts files and not for files like .cs, .css, .html, or .less. I know this is somehow caused by resharper, because if I disable resharper, the problem doesnt occur.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such functionality in ReSharper. You probably use some third-party add-in which causes this problem.

Comment: See my answer, even if not a deliberate feature, this is definitely caused by ReSharper.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed this behaviour today. It's quite frustrating as it can cause noticeable performance problems due to excessive triggering of "compile on save".

Disabling ReSharper in the Visual Studio extensions screen makes the problem go away, re-enabling the extension causes it to come back. I have no other 3rd party extensions enabled so it is undeniably caused by ReSharper.

I have logged a bug here (I don't know if it's visible to other users):
https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/2796884

In the meantime I've disabled compile on save and am compiling manually as needed.